# Is it possible to ensure a filename or path is Windows-legal using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I recently zipped up a number of files created by a script I wrote and sent them to a Windows-using colleague. He could not unzip the archive, since some of my filenames contained a `:` which isn’t legal on Windows.

It’s trivial to strip out the `:`, but what if there are other characters that I’m unaware of as being illegal in Windows path/filenames?

I wondered whether `pathlib`’s “pure” path objects would flag illegal characters in any way, but they do not as far as I can determine:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath
>>> pp = PurePosixPath("foo/bar:baz.txt")
>>> wp = PureWindowsPath(pp)
>>> print(wp)
foo\bar:baz.txt
```

Given that I do not have easy access to a Windows machine for testing, is there a simple way to ensure path/filenames generated by Python are “Windows-safe”?

Comment: It's tricky, as Maximilian Peters' link explains. If the top answer there answers your question, then we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, on Unix-like systems it's very easy to create a "fake" filesystem inside a regular file. So you could create a small NTFS or FAT32 filesystem that you could use to test filenames on.

Comment: @PM2Ring The top answer there seems to assume access to a Windows system. Also, it was written before `pathlib` became part of the standard library … and I was kind of hoping that `pathlib` might provide a solution. That said, it probably does provide an answer, namely: It can’t be done. (Your suggestion of using a virtual filesystem is useful!)

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution would just be to avoid using reserved windows characters when building out your filename.

Looking at the following link: [Naming Files, Path and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) it quotes the following as being Windows illegal characters:

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
> The following reserved characters:
>
> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)

Comment: They are illegal for a filename but not for a path. `c:\temp\tmp.txt` is a valid path but not a valid filename.

Comment: IIRC, MS filesystems don't like `\n` in filenames, either.

Comment: Agreed, some of those characters are reserved for use in file paths but not filenames

Comment: I think this is nonetheless usable. Just split your filename by `"\\"`, then ignore item `[0]` and for the rest of the list, check there's none of the above characters included. You could also add `\n`, but I find that a bit moot...